# In Perl, I am not able to join a thread when another child process is running which was forked using open

Tags: multithreading, perl, join, pipe

I want to do following things from main thread/process:

1. Communicate to another process using pipe.
2. Create threads to do certain task.
3. Wait for all the threads to complete.

Following is the pseudo code I am trying:

```
 use threads;
 use IO::Handle;
 sub dummy {
      print "\n!!!!". $$;
      return 0;
 }

 open($handle, "| cat -v") || die "Unable to open connection to BT Driver: $!\n";

 $handle->autoflush(1);

 #close $handle; If I uncomment this, threads can be joined. But I don't want to terminate this child process.

 $thr2 = threads->create(\&dummy);
 sleep 2;
 print "\n$thr2";
 foreach $thr (threads->list(threads::joinable))
 {
      print "\nIam here";
      print "\n!!!". $thr;
      $thr->join();
 }
```

Code gets stuck when I try to join the thread even though it is joinable.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? 
I am using Perl 5.10.0

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"? What exactly happens?

Comment: By getting stuck I mean the program doesn't terminates or goes further. $thr-> join call blocks the code. If I remove join call program exits with 1 active-finished-unjoined thread. I am getting following output:                                                                 [root@pe-lt154 ~]# perl thread_trial.pl 

    !!!!9441
    threads=SCALAR(0x9dbfed0)
    Iam here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a 5.10.0 with threads compiled to try it, but 5.12.4 hangs at "Iam here".  5.14.1 runs to completion.

Perl threads have a lot of bugs, but it's gotten much better in recent years.  5.10.0 is probably going to be full of bugs and the simplest way to solve it (and a lot of problems) is to just upgrade Perl.